# Hefferon Linear Algebra. Breaking the code letters in AHAHA + TEHE = TEHAW

Tags: linear-algebra

There is something I do not understand with the following problem:
"Laugh at this: AHAHA + TEHE = TEHAW. It resulted from substituting a code letter for each digit of a simple example in addition, and it is required to identify the letters and prove the solution unique."

I can find the solution by guess and check easily, but I can't make up the system of equations needed to prove the solution is unique. In particular, I can't understand why the solution book (given by Hefferon) says the fact that A<H implies that there can be no carry from the units or hundreds columns. I just can't see why.

[Edit:] According to the book: "A comparison of the units and hundreds columns of this addition shows that there must be a
carry from the tens column. The tens column then tells us that $A < H$, so there
can be no carry from the units or hundreds columns. The five columns then give
the following five equations.

$$A + E = W$$

$$2H = A + 10$$

$$H = W + 1$$
$$H + T = E + 10$$

$$A + 1 = T$$

The five linear equations in five unknowns, if solved simultaneously, produce the
unique solution: $A = 4, T = 5, H = 7, W = 6$ and $E = 2$, so that the original
example in addition was $47474 + 5272 = 52746$."

Can you help me?

Thank you very much, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write it like this :

$$ \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{AHAHA} \\
\ +\ \ \ \ \ \text{TEHE} \\
\ \ =\text{TEHAW}\\  
\\ $$

We can not make Simultaneous linear Equations , which may give Non-Integral Solutions , rather we must analyse each Decimal Position to make the Equations where the Solutions must involve Digits.

Here , we have the rightmost Place $A+E=W$ (no Carry)
or $A+E=W+10$ (with Carry).

Next Place gives $H+H=A$ (no Carry from right most Place & no Carry generated here)
or $H+H+1=A$ (with Carry from right most Place & no Carry generated here)
or $H+H=A+10$ (no Carry from right most Place & Carry generated here)
or $H+H+1=A+10$ (with Carry from right most Place & Carry generated here)
Too many Combinations ! Hence we must try something else !

Ok , right most Place , we have $A+E$ & in third Place too we have $A+E$ , yet the Sum Digit is not Same ($W$ versus $H$) , hence we must have had a Carry in Second Column.
This implies 2 things :
(1) $W+1=H$
(2) $H+H+Carry=A+10$ (where the Carry is either $0$ or $1$) , which gives $H=(A+10-Carry)/2$ which gives the claim given by Book Author.
Not sure whether this was your Question or whether you want the whole Solution.

Ok , left most Place , we have $A+0+Carry=T$ , hence there must be a Carry from 1000 Place & $A+1=T$.

Continuing in that way , we get :
$$ \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ 47474 \\
+\ \ \ \ 5272  \\
=\ \ 52746 \\
\\ $$

UPDATE:

The Author says this :
"(A) A comparison of the units and hundreds columns of this addition shows that there must be a carry from the tens column.
(B) The tens column then tells us that A < H, so there can be (C) no carry from the units or (D) hundreds columns."

Here , Claim (A) matches what we have concluded earlier.
Second Column gives $H+H+Carry=A+10$ , which gives $H=(A+10-Carry)/2$ which indicates that Carry=0 ( otherwise we will have $H=ODD/2$ ) matching Claim (C) & A is less than H , which matches Claim (B).
We are left with Claim (D) which is not Direct , but requires a little more work :
When $A+E=W$ (Column 1) & $A+E+1=H+Carry$ (Column 3) , we get $A+E+1=W+1=H+Carry$ , which gives $W+1=H+Carry$ , thus $Carry=0$ , otherwise $W=H$. This matches Claim (D).

ADDENDUM :
While checking Claim (C) , I used the unproved assumption that $A$ was Even. We can over-come that in two ways :
We can then assume $A$ was ODD , which will allow Carry from third Column , then make the Equations like the Author did , then Solve them to get no Solution.
Direct way to show Claim (C) is like this :
We have $H+H+Carry=A+10$ hence $A$ is less than $H$.
The third Column is $A+E+1=H$ (no Carry) or $A+E+1=H+10$ (with Carry)

Here , Carry is not Possible when $A$ is less than $H$ , because $E+1$ is maximum 10 , then adding that to $A$ will either warp-around to give a Smaller Digit or will not wrap-around to give a larger Digit.
We have larger Digit , hence we know that there is no wrap-around , or no Carry.
Example : $A=5$ , when we add $E+1=1,2,3,4$ we will get larger Digit $H=6,7,8,9$ , with no wrap-around. When we add $E+1=7,8,9$ , we get $H=12,13,14$ , which is a wrap-around to $H=2,3,4$ with Carry & we end up with Smaller Digit $H$.

PHEW !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have a problem though, I do not see why H=(A+10−Carry)/2 implies that there are no carry for the units and the hundreds?

Comment: Could you update the Post with the Exact wording [ Snap-Shot ] from that text Book ? Knowing that Exact wording will enable to me to respond more Correctly.

Comment: Done it, thank you for our time.

Comment: You could include more Previous Context , that line in Isolation can not imply that. Eg : When ( or If ) Author has concluded that $A$ is Even , then $H+H+Carry=A+10$ implies that $Carry=0$ , otherwise , we will get $H=ODD/2$. Thus , $A+E=W$ has no Carry.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited with the complete answer.

Comment: I have updated the Answer , thanks for the Edits to Question Post , @M.Connor , the Author was a little "Short" with Explanations , which I have elaborated.

Comment: I do not understand why otherwise we will have H=ODD/2? If Carry = 1 then H = (A+9)/2, which could be even if A is odd, no? Unless I am mistaken, we do not know about the parity of A.

Comment: Oh , good catch , I have updated the Answer with a fix !!

Comment: Oh now I see it! Thank you very much for your time @Prem!

Comment: The Author was very "terse" , thus we have to think more about the Details. Eventually , we get the Solution in various ways. Here , trying to match what the Author thought was the "tricky" Part !